# git clone error under Windows with symlinks

Tags: windows, git, symbolic-link, clone

I get "warning: the following paths have collided (e.g. case-sensitive paths on a case-insensitive filesystem) and only one from the same colliding group is in the working tree" error, when using git clone:

```
git clone -c core.symlinks=true ssh://root@11.22.33.44/etc c/Dev/GIT/mysite-etckeeper/
Cloning into 'c/Dev/GIT/mysite-etckeeper'...
remote: Counting objects: 1400, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1202/1202), done.
remote: Total 1400 (delta 195), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (1400/1400), 3.71 MiB | 276.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (195/195), done.
Checking out files: 100% (1154/1154), done.
warning: the following paths have collided (e.g. case-sensitive paths
on a case-insensitive filesystem) and only one from the same
colliding group is in the working tree:

  'HOSTNAME'
  'hostname'


/etc # ls -la HOSTNAME
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         8 Mar 29  2017 HOSTNAME -> hostname

/etc # ls -la hostname
-rw-r--r--   1 root root        18 Dec 21  2016 hostname
```

How can I fix this problem?
This symlink issue is causing other problems, too.

Here is an the example repo to reproduce the error:
https://github.com/klorinczi/test_dupe_filename

```
Execute this:

$ git clone -c core.symlinks=true https://github.com/klorinczi/test_dupe_filename 
Cloning into 'test_dupe_filename_example'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 9 (delta 0), reused 9 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (9/9), done.
warning: the following paths have collided (e.g. case-sensitive paths
on a case-insensitive filesystem) and only one from the same
colliding group is in the working tree:

  'HOSTNAME'
  'hostname'
```

Comment: There is no solution to this. As the error mentions the system isn't able to handle files that have the same name but different cases.

Comment: IIRC Git for Windows has an option when installing that addresses symlinks

Comment: Doesn't `core.symlinks=true` address symlinks issue?

Comment: This error isn’t about symlinks though...? It’s about a name collision. Coincidentally one of the items is a symlink, yes. But that’s not the problem.

Comment: This question has already been answered on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59643532/git-clone-error-under-windows-with-symlinks

Answer (score 1):

It's not a symlink issue, it's a an issue with case-insensitive file systems.

On a case-sensitive file system, the files `ReadMe.txt`, `Readme.txt`, `README.txt` are three different files. On a case-insensitive file system, they are the same file.

By default Windows and macOS use case-insensitive file systems. NTFS itself is case-sensitive but Windows uses it only case-insensitive. HFS+ and APFS can be case-sensitive but by default they are not. Most UNIX systems and Linux however use case-sensitive file systems by default.

The problem is that there is a file named `hostname` and a symlink to that file named `HOSTNAME`. On a case-sensitive file system these are two different names and thus both, the file and the symlink can exist in the same directory.

On a case-insensitive system, though, `hostname` and `HOSTNAME` are the same filename and the same file cannot once be a file and once a symlink.

If a Git repo shall work on case-insensitive file systems, all users of that repo should have

```
ignorecase = true
```

in their Git config file. If that is true, Git also treats all objects as the same object if their name only differs by case. In that case it wouldn't even be possible to check-in `hostname` and `HOSTNAME` into the same repository as Git would see it as the same file and one file would overwide the other one in the repo.

To fix your situation:

1. Delete the symlink: `git rm -f HOSTNAME`
2. Restore the file: `git restore hostname`
3. Commit: `git ci -m "Fix hostname/HOSTNAME name conflict"`

Step 2 is only required on case-insensitive file systems as here deleting either one of the two will always delete the file on disk (as I said, from the file system perspective both are the same file).

If the file need to be all upper case for some reason, perform the same steps as above, followed by a double rename:

1. `git mv hostname hostname_2`
2. `git mv hostname_2 HOSTNAME`
3. `git ci -m "Rename hostname to HOSTNAME"`

On a case-insensitive system, changing case always requires a double rename. This is also true on a case-sensitive one if `ignorecase = true` has been set.